# Typescript: Ensure all interface properties are specified when using `as` keyword

Tags: typescript

I have found lots of posts about how to make optional properties of a typescript interface possible, but I want it the other way around, make all of them mandatory.

The only constraint is that I want it to happen when using the `as` keyword.

So given this interface:

```
export interface StoreActionDispatchedInterface {
  type: SnackBarActions;
  payload: object;
}
```

and then I want to use it like this:

```
  store.dispatch({
    type: SnackBarActions.HIDE_SNACKBAR
  } as StoreActionDispatchedInterface);
```

because I want to avoid doing this (*):

```
  const actionDispatched: StoreActionDispatchedInterface = {
    type: SnackBarActions.HIDE_SNACKBAR
  };

  store.dispatch(actionDispatched);
```

This step (*) is detected properly by visual studio as not meeting the requirements of the `StoreActionDispatchedInterface` (the `payload` property is missing)

Although I have been searching in the typescript website, I don't understand why the `as` keyword allows me to not have the `payload` property but when declaring the variable `actionDispatched` of the interface type as in (*) visual studio detects that `payload` is missing.

Any ideas please, why `as` and the `:type` work differently?

Comment: Because otherwise I can never meet the requirement if I parse a JSON to an object and I know it satisfies that interface. Than I would need to manually write out all sorts of copy logic.

Comment: This is not what the `as` keyword does and it cannot be used for this.

Comment: I would suspect it is because in the as example the object you are building is at first a type of "any" and the as is casting it so perhaps it isn't as tight with those rules, whilst in the :type example you explicitly set its type to be your interface and thus it has to fulfill that interface else it is an incomplete implementation of that type

Comment: `as` is a cast. It means "consider this to be the specified type even though it doesn't quite look like it."

Comment: @ccarton yes! but if I am telling the compiler to consider something as being of a type by using the `as` keyword, then I don't understand why the compiler doesn't realise that `payload` is missing?

Comment: It does know that it's missing. It doesn't generate an error because that what `as` is supposed to do. You use `as` when you explicitly don't want an error. You're saying: "I know this would normally be an error, but just do it anyway this time without an error please"